# Создание двойной кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf

По логике выглядит как 2 кнопки, одна маленькая другая большая.
Первая работает как кнопка а другая как выпадающий список.

**При нажатии на кнопку**

[image: При нажатии]

**При нажатии другую**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать такую кнопку?

Comment: Это комбобокс с кнопкой внутри. Сейчас попробую застилизовать

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ну например так. Положите кнопку на комбобокс. Утащите комбобокс под кнопку при помощи `ZIndex`. Застилизуйте `ComboBoxItem`, чтобы он показывал сепараторы в нужных местах. Выйдет что-то такое:

```xml
<Grid Height="20">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="20"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Text,ElementName=cb}"/>
    <ComboBox IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="DisplayName"
              Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="cb" Panel.ZIndex="-1">
        <ComboBox.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <!-- если на входе null, то... -->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <!-- не разрешаем выбирать этот элемент, и... -->
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        <!-- показываем вместо него разделитель -->
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate>
                                    <Separator/>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ComboBox.Resources>
    </ComboBox>
</Grid>
```

В `DataContext` в свойстве `Items` будет коллекция таких элементов:

```cs
class SelectItem
{
    public string DisplayName { get; }
    // тут другие члены
}
```

примерно такого вида:

```cs
new List<SelectItem>()
{
    new SelectItem { DisplayName = "Case insensitive" },
    null,
    new SelectItem { DisplayName = "Integer" },
    new SelectItem { DisplayName = "Positive integers" },
    new SelectItem { DisplayName = "Negative integers" },
    new SelectItem { DisplayName = "Year (1900-2099)" },
    null,
    new SelectItem { DisplayName = "AVI (*.avi)" },
    new SelectItem { DisplayName = "JPEG (*.jpg; *.jpeg)" },
    new SelectItem { DisplayName = "MKV (*.mkv)" },
    new SelectItem { DisplayName = "AVI (*.avi)" },
    null,
    new SelectItem { DisplayName = "Do not contain SUBSTRING" },
    new SelectItem { DisplayName = "Whitespace" }
}
```

Получается что-то такое:

[image: картинка, как же без неё?]

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Vladimir: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Прицеп понятен, осталось красоту навести и подумать как это сделать стилем(чтобы использовать когда нужна будет  такая кнопка).

Comment: @Vladimir: Возможно, лучше из этого сделать UserControl